# Assistance optimizing server with high-traffic

Tags: nginx, webserver, fastcgi, vps

I am in need of some help. Currently, I have the following package:

2048 MB
80gb RAID 10 Disk Space
4x CPU Priority
5000 GB bandwidth
CentOS

(VPS-4)
http://www.knownhost.com/vps_packages.html

My VPS has been receiving a lot of traffic. It had 1 million page views on one day, even!

As cool as that is, we have been plagued with problems ever since the dramatic rise in hits.

We were using SuPHP at first, which was getting resource-intensive. The server would go down every couple of days and we would receive automated emails about excessive processes running.

We then switched to FastCGI. This has been running great and we stopped getting those emails. However, during peak time, if there are a lot of people connected, then web pages wont show. You will have to refresh the page a couple of times to get it to show (sounds as if all connection slots are held up).

We are currently using NGINX + Apache w/ CPANEL + eAccelerator + FastCGI on this server.

Ignoring the current setup configuration and keeping in mind the hardware we are using, do you guys have any suggested configuration that may be best at supporting all these hits?

Please keep in mind that the large amount of hits occurs one ONE page (don't ask!). The page has barely any PHP on it (but is partially dynamic so the PHP is needed) and doesn't even connect to a database.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds like the connection gets pooled until a thread becomes available. Maybe this answer can be of help http://serverfault.com/questions/191251/apache-maximum-number-of-threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout this, I will modify the **nginx** config. Apache can stay as it is.

**Step 1**: Deploy gzip compression

This step is pretty simple - gzip-compress output.

```
gzip             on;
gzip_min_length  1000;
gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types       text/plain application/xml application/json;
```

All that this will do is enable gzip compression for: text/html (default), application/xml, application/json and text/plain. I'm assuming that you are serving images from CDN, by the way. If not, enable that for them too.

This should see a drop in your used bandwidth, but offset this by a slight CPU cost. However, CPU is rarely the bottleneck - usually, it's bandwidth and disk I/O, especially on static sites, so we're going to be working on that.

**Step 2 (optional)**: Drop apache if you can

If you're just serving static content, nginx by itself is worth having. If you're using fastCGI already, consider PHP-FPM, which allows you to short out the memory hog that Apache is.

**Step 3**: Caching through headers

This will lower bandwidth usage by forcing a locally-cached version of all pages served by nginx. Pretty cool stuff as it will completely prevent clients from re-downloading something they already have.

```
expires       24h;
add_header    Cache-Control  public;
```

This step will also have an unsought advantage: apache will get fewer queries.

**Step 4**: in-memory page caching

This step will take your page out of disk I/O and into memory. If you have one static page, you should see a significant gain by doing this. [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy) has a lot about this. Covering it would take a serious amount of time.

This will have two advantages:

- nginx will more often load from memory rather than querying apache, reducing in a lighter load on Apache
- Apache itself, due to this, will read from disk and fork workers less often

Once all this is done, you should see a decrease in load, possibly enough to lower the number of workers on Apache.

Comment: Thank you for all that! I'll give it a shot. The site that gets most of the traffic though does have some PHP on it so it isn't 100% static. Not sure if caching will help that very much.

Comment: @Mike: This question is answerable only if you know what the PHP script does in detail. That's a service I offer to clients professionally, by the way - analysis and efficient caching. There's brute-force caching on clients through headers, but there are also a lot of layers people forget: you can do in-app caching using a tool such as **memcached**, and nginx also supports it, to lighten repetitive computation on data, for example.

Comment: The PHP script just outputs some random messages (it can't be done using JavaScript since people could view all the messages that way in the JS file). We have it setup in such a way that the messages show based on percentages. I.e. message #1 shows 1% of the time. Message #2 can show 30% of the time, etc. Really simple stuff really, but unfortunately we don't have a legitimate way to not do it in PHP. It's kind of like promo codes being hidden, but showing up on rare occasions.

Comment: That's fine. However, this begs the question - do you really need the entire PHP stack for this? You could just as easily use nginx's perl engine to generate random numbers and verify based on that, also in nginx, by caching by key-value pair according to the random number. This shorts out PHP entirely. (If you don't want to do this, at least consider switching to PHP-FPM by proxypass on nginx. Apache has been known to be a memory and CPU hog)

Comment: Finally -- I had enough points to +1 your answer :) Anyway, we unfortunately do need the PHP stack, as we also have other websites on the server (which get a lot less traffic) using WordPress.

Comment: PHP-FPM will allow you to keep it (and then more). That's probably a better pick than running apache just for that... especially if your PHP is CGI already.

Comment: You can offload the code using Ajax and make that page completely static. This has the advantage that spiders won't hit the php engine.